# HTML Canvas Double Click Highlight Issue

Tags: html, canvas, click, double

I have an HTML canvas and I have implemented a simple double click function. When the page contains only a canvas, everything works fine. However, as soon as I add, for example, a simple text input field, everytime I double click strange things start to get highlighted (try randomly clicking on certain parts of this page and a similar situation arises).

What's the best way to get around this? Do I need to enclose the canvas in something (I tried enclosing it in a table but that made the situation worse) or do I need to disconnect a specific signal.

Thanks

Comment: could you be more specific on the "highlight"-thing? What is highlighted and how does this look?

Comment: @Chris I have a text field entry and whenever I double click on the canvas the entire text field gets highlighted. My guess is that the HTML 'cursor' is situated top left and when I double click on the canvas everything between is highlighted. I will take Matt's advice below and look at the other links. They look helpful. Cheers